# How to solve: TypeError: grid[i][j] is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, global-variables

I'm trying to build a grid and store each cell of the grid as an objet in an array named grid. I've defined grid as a global variable, so I can fill it using createGrid() and then read it using drawGrid().

I want to implement the grid as part of a canvas animation tutorial. My code is:

```js
var grid = [];

function drawGrid() {
  for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    grid[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
      if (grid[i][j].food === 0) {
        console.log("Has a good value")
      }
    }
  }
}

function Cell(i, ii) {
  this.i = i;
  this.ii = ii;
  this.food = false;
}

function createGrid() {
  for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    grid[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
      grid[i][j] = new Cell(i, j);
    }
  }
}

function mainLoop() {
  clearCanvas();
  drawGrid();

  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop)
}

createGrid();
mainLoop();
```

I create the grid before calling the loop, so once the function drawGrid() is invoqued, grid has been already filled. I do not place createGrid() inside the loop because is not necessary to create the grid each time and also because it needs a lot of resources each time the loop runs

The browser throws the error here:

```
if (grid[i][j].food === false) {
  console.log("Has a good value")
}
```

Comment: your line `grid[i] = [];` delete all you created previously.

Comment: `cols` and `rows` are not defined, I can't test your code

Comment: @Marange there is nowhere `if(grid[i][j].food===false){ ` in your code

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Thanks, that was the problem. I was overwriting the array.

Answer (score 0):

since the value tested is of Boolean type, writing `if (grid[i][j].food === false) {` is nonsense.

you have to code as follows: `if (grid[i][j].food) {` to realize the condition if the value is true
otherwise, if we want to realize the condition if it is false: `if (!grid[i][j].food) {`

it is still necessary that the values i and j are correct ( i = zero to cols-1, etc.)